# Deleting Linux swap partition

Tags: 14.04, windows, swap

I have a dual boot machine of Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows 7.
What will happen if I delete the Linux **swap partition** from win7 using some partition manager software.
Will it cause problem to my Linux or it will function smoothly as earlier.

Comment: Why delete it "from win7"? You can remove it correctly from Ubuntu.

Comment: Will it cause any problem to linux?

Comment: Yes, it will cause problems if you do it from Win7.

Comment: So,can linux work without any swap?

Comment: Yes, it can. But how good will it run depends on your RAM size and your tasks.

Comment: You can just do `swapoff <partition>` and see how it goes. You can then turn it back on with `swapon <partition>`.

Comment: @Pilot6, no, it won't.  What program deletes the partition makes no difference; it will be missing when you boot next and the system will complain about that until you remove its entry from /etc/fstab.

Comment: So it is a problem already. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum, you'll get an error report during Ubuntu startup, saying the swap partition isn't found.  Depending on exact details, this may prevent Ubuntu from starting and drop you to an emergency shell.  However, if you have enough RAM (typically, for Ubuntu, 4 GB or more), Ubuntu should at least finish starting with no swap; the error happens because Ubuntu *expects* to find a swap partition.

Even *if* Ubuntu starts successfully without a swap partition (in my experience, this will happen only if you didn't create one during installation, but there may be other circumstances that permit it), you'll have trouble if running processes begin to require more RAM than the physical RAM available in hardware; for instance, if you have 4 GB installed, and load programs that, together, need more than 4 GB, you'll run into issues with extremely slow performance and possibly even a system freeze.

Because of this, I'd recommend against deleting your swap partition.  They're typically small, compared to the size of modern hard disks or even SSDs, and they're part of how Ubuntu performs as well as it does.